# Chaining serialized Deferred for posting data

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, jquery-deferred

I am using Firebase and attempting to use jQuery Deferred when I post data to a series of locations. I want a mechanism where if any of the posts fail, I want to recover and possibly undo previous posts.

**The syntax for doing a Firebase post is**

```
var fbRef = new Firebase("https://my.firebaseIO.com/path/to/data");
fbRef.set(data,function (error){
   if (error){
      // do something about it
   } else {
      // all went well
      // next post would go here...
   }
}
```

Naturally writing a series of posts this way - where each depends on the success of the previous will result in the pyramiding of code AKA callback hell.

**For my concrete example, I have data about 'words' that need to be put at various locations**

```
/words/upCase/<word>/id =<word>
/words/upCase/<word>/type = <type>
/words/<type>/<word>/id = <word>
```

Each of these will have its own Firebase `set(data,cb)` call, and the latter two should not be conducted should any of their precedents fail. This is a simplified example, so the solution should be geared to many more data points.

Also, in this example there is no flow of data from one operation to the next, all data is known at the start, so I am also interested in data flow examples.

**My latest attempt involves genericizing the callback**

```
// function factory. function will set firebase reference value and handle the deferred if exists
var makeFn=function (fbr,val,task){
  return function (){
    fbr.set(val,function (err){
      if (err) {
        console.log(fbr.toString()+'  Error in Firebase:'+err.toSource());
        if (task) {
          task.reject(err);
        }
      }
      if (task) {
        task.resolve(fbr);
      }
    });
    if (task) {
      return task.promise();
    }
  }
}
// factory that returns a function that returns a promise about setting data
var make=function (fbr,val){
  return function (){
    var task=new $.Deferred();
    return makeFn(fbr,val,task)();
  }
};
```

**Then I call like this**

```
var fbr = new Firebase("https://my.firebaseIO.com/words/upCase/" + word + "/id");

make(fbr,word)() // set id promise
.done(makeFn(fbr.parent().child('type'),type)) // HERE, not right
.done(makeFn(fbr.parent().parent().parent().child(type).child(word).child('id'),word)) // set third data, still not right
.done(function(){
          //inform all went well
        }
);
```

My attempt is not chaining dependencies as I intend. What I want to say is...

```
make(fbr,word).done(<new promise returning fn>).<get the done of that new promise>(...)
```

... without pyramiding like:

```
make(fbr,word).done(
                  <new promise returning fn>.done(
                                                  ...
                                                  )
                  )
```

The one thing I am sure of is that I am doing something wrong. How do I chain dependencies without pyramiding my code? Treat me as if I am new to promises, because I am. =)

**UPDATE**

Here is a walk-through of what I've come up with. This just deals with setters.

First extend `Firebase` to return what I call a promisy function when we want to set, I am just using `.s()` here...

```
Firebase.prototype.s=function(v){
  var fn=makeSet(this,v);
  return fn;
};
```

Here is the maker, it has some commonalities...

```
var makeSet=function (fbr, val){
  // factory that returns a function that returns a promise about setting data
  var task=Q.defer();
  var fn=setFn(fbr,val,task);
  makeCOMMON(task,fn,fbr);
  return fn;
};
```

In the commonalities, we link functions and promises, and also create a new kind of `.then()` that returns the promise of the fn fed into it, its called `.ok()`.

```
var makeCOMMON=function (task, fn, fbr){
  var p=task.promise;
  fn.task=task;
  fn.fbr=fbr.toString();
  fn.p=p;
  p.fbr=fbr.toString();
  p.fn=fn;
  p.ok=function (fnn){
    this.then(fnn);
    return fnn.p;
  };
}
```

That part is probably redundant, and maybe iffy, it exposes my ignorance. Back to `setFn()`:

```
var setFn=function (fbr, val, task){
  // function factory. function will set firebase reference value and handle the deferred if exists
  return function (){
    task.notify('Setting '+fbr.toString()+' to '+val.toSource());
    fbr.set(val,function (err){
      if (err) {
        task.notify('Rejecting Update due to error '+fbr.toString());
        task.reject({
          error:err,
          FbPath:fbr.toString(),
          FbTask:task,
          FbVal:val,
          toString:function(){
            var s='';
            s+=' '+this.error.toString();
            s+=' '+this.FbPath;
            if (this.FbVal) {
              s+=' '+this.FbVal.toSource();
            }else{
              s+=' null';
            }
            return s;
          }
        });//reject
      }else{
        task.resolve(fbr);
      }
    });
    return task.promise;
  };
}
```

The tension builds... now, when I go to call that, I have a chainer mechanism:

```
add:function(w,type){
  w=w.toLowerCase();
  var fn0,fnLast;
  var fbr=FirebaseSvc.get();
  var proms=[];
  //
  var chain=function(fbrFn){
    var wasFirst=false;
    if (typeof fn0=='undefined') {
      wasFirst=true;
      fn0=fbrFn;
    }
    proms.push(fbrFn.p);
    fbrFn.p.progress(logProgress);
    fbrFn.p.fail(logFail);
    if (!wasFirst) {
      var rv=fnLast.p.ok(fbrFn);
      fnLast=fbrFn;
      return rv;
    }else{
      fnLast=fbrFn;
      return fbrFn.p;
    }
  };
  //
  //.c() is .child() alias
  chain(fbr.root().c('words/upCase/'+w+'/id').s(w));//This is returing a promise, so I can still do promisy things, but I am not right now
  chain(fbr.root().c('words/upCase/'+w+'/type').s(type));
  chain(fbr.root().c('words/words'+type+'/'+w+'/id').s(w));
  //
  var ro={
    promise:Q.all(proms),
    doIt:fn0
  };
  return ro;
},//.add
```

From the client, it is:

```
var ro=WordSvc.add(w,type);
ro.promise...// can attach handlers
ro.doIt();// kick it all off
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand but something like this should do the job.

First, two utility functions :

```
function fbSet(path) {
    var dfrd = $.Deferred(),
        fbRef = new Firebase("https://my.firebaseIO.com/" + path);
    fbRef.set(data, function (error) {
       if (error) {
          dfrd.reject(fbRef, error);
       } else {
          dfrd.resolve(fbRef);
       }
    }
    return dfrd.promise();
}

function doFbChain(paths, word, type) {
    var dfrd = $.Deferred();
    $.each(paths, function(i, path) {
        path = path.replace('<word>', word).replace('<type>', type);
        dfrd = dfrd.then(fb(path));
    });
    return dfrd.promise();
}
```

Now, some sample application code :

```
var myPaths = [
    '/words/upCase/<word>/id',
    '/words/upCase/<word>/type',
    '/words/<type>/<word>/id'
];
var myWord = 'myWord';
var myType = 'myType';

doFbChain(myPaths, myWord, myType).done(function() {
    //overall success
}).error(function(fbRef, error) {
    //failure somewhere along the way
});
```

You will need to play around with the code to get it to behave exactly as you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a more generic solution. You do correctly understand the problem. I am going to update the post and maybe you would like to review it. Its going to be very convoluted, but its all for getting the client call nice and neat.

Comment: Tried to penetrate the updated question but succeeded only in becoming thoroughly confused. I still think you need to build a conventional `.then()` chain.

Comment: Maybe my confusion is coming from jQuery, I've since switched to Q. jQuery has faults because the spec did not make clear what happens in a .then() function return -- ie undefined. Correct?
I need to know how to reject/resolve inside my (promiseless) function given to .then(). And, if my function returns a promise, does that promise come out the other side of .then(<my fn>).<here>?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: I know jQuery much better than Q. They are indeed different. jQuery's .then() behaviour is very well documented and thoroughly reliable (though not loved by Q people).

Comment: When you `return` from within a `.then()`, it creates a new deferred chain that additional callbacks will be attached to.  If you don't `return` from within `.then()`, it behaves as `.done()` and additional callbacks will be attached to the original chain.  The reason behind this is in the documentation and has to do with deprecating `.pipe()` to be 'more' Q like.  I think it adds confusion and still isn't 100% the spec.